# How do you take the contents of a combo box and add them to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I've seen a lot about adding the contents of an `Array` to a `ComboBox`, but not the other way around. I would like to take the contents of a `ComboBox` add them to an `Array` to be sent to another method for processing.

I've already got the `.Items.Count` to determine the size of the `Array`, but I can't figure out how to cycle through the items in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: `foreach(var item in .Items)`?

Comment: public void Ingredients()
            {
                string[] ingredients = new     string[ingredientComboBox.Items.Count];
            foreach (var item in ingredientComboBox.Items)
                 {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.Length; i++)
                        ingredients[i] = item.ToString();
                }

Comment: i can't seem to make that look like code here, sorry, but something like that?

Comment: MVC or WebForms? Are you only interested in Selected Items or all items added to the box?

Comment: windows form, looking at all items in the combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   string[] items = new string[currentComboBox.Items.Count];

   for(int i = 0; i < currentComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
   {
       items[i] = currentComboBox.Items[i].ToString();
   }
```

Answer (score 11):

From looking at your comments on your question you probably want this:

```
var arr = ingredientComboBox.Items.Cast<Object>()
          .Select(item => item.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I get the error, system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection does not contain a definition for Select

Comment: @CraigSmith aha, `ObjectCollection` is not a generic collection. Try adding `.Cast<Object>()` after `Items`. See update.

Comment: tried your fix and it compiles, but already got answer 3 working. Thanks for your input!!

Comment: @CraigSmith Ok, if you use that answer make sure you set the size of the array to the size of the items collection of the ComboBox rather than 20.

Comment: Got that figured out already. That one was closer to what I was already trying, was missing the .ToString at the end of the line.